# Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $2p$ for a prime $p>2$, $A, B \leq G$ s.t $|A|=p, |B|=2$, then $AB=G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a non-abelian group of order $2p$ for a prime $p>2$.

As a small part of an exercise I am trying to show that if we take $A, B \leq G$ s.t $|A|=p, |B|=2$ (existence guranteed by Sylow) then $AB=G$. but I'm having trouble showing that.

I thought about looking at $B \curvearrowright G/A$ by left multiplication, if we could show it is transitive that is enough I think.

Comment: $A$ is a normal subgroup, because it is of index $2$. So $G=A\ltimes B$ and hence $G=AB$.

Comment: what I am trying to show is that  G=A⋉B... don't you need G=AB first to claim it is true?

Comment: It depends on what you know. Strictly speaking it is a duplicate, since the only such group is $D_{p}$, which is a semidirect product.

Comment: Why did you close my question? It is different...

Comment: It is exactly what you have asked for, namely why is it a semidirect product, i.e., $G=AB$ (and trivial intersection). So the answer is, because $G=D_p=C_p\ltimes C_2$ and hence $G=AB$. See also Shaun's answer below. In fact, it **is** your exercise.

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is what I am trying to prove, and I'm looking to show specifically how G=AB without the entire theorem in the first place... So I suggest you don't close my question.

Comment: $G=AB$ basically is exactly that it is a semidirect product. It is really the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ has index $2$ in $G$, it must be normal (you can also show this with the sylow theorems, since $A$ is a sylow $p$-subgroup). But since $A$ is normal and $B$ is a subgroup, we know $AB \leq G$  (by one of the [isomorphism theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_B_(groups))).

But of course, $|AB| = |G|$, so $AB$ must actually equal *all* of $G$!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, but why $|AB|=|G|$?
I don't think it is trivial since it should rely on $G$ being non-abelian.

Comment: We know that $|AB| = \frac{|A| \ |B|}{|A \cap B|}$, but since $A$ is a $p$-sylow subgroup it cannot contain any elements of order $2$, whereas $B$ contains exactly one element of order $2$, so their intersection is $\{e\}$, and $|AB| = |A| \ |B|$.

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm a little confused since this should only be true if $G$ is non-abelian and you didn't use it. Am I missing something?

Comment: The claim is true even when $G$ is abelian. We just get a _direct_ product $A \times B$ instead of a semidirect product $A \ltimes B$. This is actually still fine, since a direct product is just a very simple semidirect product.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a group of order $2p$, where $p$ is a prime greater than $2$. Then $G$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{2p}$ or $D_p$.

For a proof, see **Theorem 7.3** of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.